# Rails4: Template is missing error with PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, pdfkit

I'd like to generate PDF file, so I am trying to use PDFKit but failing.

The following error was displayed when I click the link.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template /show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
  * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"
```

**schedules\show.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, @schedule.title) %>
<%= render @schedules %>
```

**schedules\ _schedule.html.erb**

```
...
    <%= link_to "PDF", schedule_path(schedule.id, format: "pdf"), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default" %>
...
```

**schedules_controller.rb**

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.pdf do
    html = render_to_string template: "show"

    pdf = PDFKit.new(html, encoding: "UTF-8")

    send_data pdf.to_pdf,
      filename:    "#{@scheudles.id}.pdf",
      type:        "application/pdf",
      disposition: "inline"
  end
end
...
```

Although I create `show.pdf.erb` and `_schedule.pdf.erb` which contents is the same as `html.erb`, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `Missing template /show` is because from the controller using `template: "show"` isn't specific enough for rails to know where in your views folder to find the `show` file.

You can see the evidence of this in your error where it says it searched for `show` inside `../app/views`. You need to use the template parent folder along with the template name.

change this

```
format.pdf do
  html = render_to_string template: "show"
  ...
end
```

to this

```
format.pdf do
  html = render_to_string template: "schedules/show.html.erb"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @MilesStanfield. Although I changed to `schedules/show.html.erb`, the following error is appeared. `RuntimeError (command failed (exitstatus=0): /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf --encoding UTF-8 --page-size A4 --margin-top 0.25in --margin-right 1in --margin-bottom 0.25in --margin-left 1in - -):`

Comment: your one step closer now :) I helped you past your previous error and would appreciate an upvote. good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer,@MilesStanfield. My problem may be another cause as you mentioned. It would be appreciated if you could be check another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471547/rails-how-to-display-font-awesome-icons-on-pdf)

Comment: i looked. but sorry to say i dont have an answer for that problem

Answer (score 0):

just change `:action => "show.html.erb"`

`html = render_to_string(:layout => false , :action => "show.pdf.erb")`

Hope this helps you.